# AMQ9504: A protocol error was detected for channel

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7

I'm unable to connect remotely from WebSphere Application Server with Queue Manager at WebSphere MQ. Anyhow it get connected to Queue Manager from WAS that is installed on same machine. I'm using version 7.5 of WebSphere MQ and version 7.0 of WebSphere Application Server.

While attempting to connect WAS remotely to Queue Manager following error messages were logged.

**Error Message from WebSphere MQ:**

> 1/30/2013 21:12:09 - Process(3624.6) User(MUSR_MQADMIN)
>   Program(amqrmppa.exe)
>                         Host(KHILT-269) Installation(Installation1)
>                         VRMF(7.5.0.0) QMgr(QM.TEST)
>                         AMQ9504: A protocol error was detected for channel 'TEST_CHANNEL'. EXPLANATION: During communications with the
>   remote queue manager, the channel program detected a protocol error.
>   The failure type was 11 with associated data of 0. ACTION: Contact the
>   systems administrator who should examine the error logs to determine
>   the cause of the failure.

**Error Message at WebSphere Application Server:**

> A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following
>   reason: CC=2;RC=2009

As it can be seen from logs, I have created Queue Manager as QM.TEST and channel as TEST_CHANNEL. The listener port defined for the Queue Manager is 1417 along with protocol TCP.

I did lot of google but didn't find any appropriate solution. I appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks in adv, KAmeer

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I have WAS 7 and WMQ 7.5. I was able to make a connection to my existing WMQ 7.0 QM but not my new WMQ 7.5 QM. Apparently there was a change to the WMQ components bundled with WAS 7 after the initial release 7.0.0.0. After updating the resource adapter I was able to make a successfull connection to both queue managers.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, can you please tell how did you update the resource adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The queue manager generates protocol error and terminates the connection immediately when it receives unexpected TSH flow from the client. As a result the client receives 2009 error. Technically, low level MQ client will be able communicate with higher version MQ queue manager and vice versa unless there are known restrictions and/or there is a MQ defect/APAR. The error message indicates the queue manager is running at MQ 7500 and this is MQ base 7.5 version. It is recommended upgrading the queue manager to the latest fixpack available to rule out any known problems. You could also try disabling shared conversion on the SVRCONN(i.e. setting SHARECNV to 0) channel and check whether it workarounds the problem until the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Open a PMR with IBM as this sounds like a bug.

Comment: But at the same time I'm able to connect remotely to another Queue Manager from same WAS. So I don't think so its a bug, there is some issue with Queue Manager's configuration at my end.

Answer (score 0):

the cause for this is mq 7 client cannot talk to mq 7.5, the client needs to use mq 7.5 jar files

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. In my case was the mq library that was doing an MQGET with an infinite loop, so the lib was locked on the mqget while i called the kill and generated an event and tried to disconnect while the get was still running. As the mqget does not support unlocking via signal, i had to change the code to not stay infinite on get and add some flags on the kill command so the app could detect that it was time to die, when it returned from the get.