# A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following reason (reason '2538')

Tags: java, ibm-mq

While trying to configure JMS Queue connection factories/Activation specification on Websphere Application Sever 8.5 and RAD 8.5.1 I get following error:

```
 A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following reason: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2'
('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

Can anybody please suggest this could be because of what reason?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609511/amq9504-a-protocol-error-was-detected-for-channel

Answer (score 2):

The host your queue manager is running on is not reachable. In the connection factory have you provided the correct host name, does the queue manager have a running listener for the provided port, is the host and port allowed in the firewall?

You should try the host and port with telnet to check.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the hostname, port name, and queueManager name are correct.
- Go to -> QueueManager -> Listener.
- Search for `LISTENER.TCP`.
- The status should be in Running state. Otherwise Start it by right-clicking.

Comment: Can I found this in IBM MQ Explorer either where?

Comment: Yes, You will find in the IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer. Same steps QueueManager ->